# Find DataGrid for DataGridColumn

Tags: silverlight, attached-properties

How can I get the `DataGrid` for a given `DataGridColumn`.  I've created an attached property in a subclass of `DataGrid` that applies to `DataGridColumn` (which I've not subclassed). It gives me the `DataGridColumn` on which I apply the attached property, but how do I get the `DataGrid` reference itself?  I need both.

**Edit:**

What I'm more interested in, is how in the event handler for an attached property does one get the `DependencyObject` instance that is actually hosting the attached property.  That is, the `DataGrid` instead of the `DataGridColumn` that the property is attached too.

```
<my:MvvmDataGrid x:Name="_dataGrid" ... >
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn my:MvvmDataGrid.SingleClickEdit="true" .../>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:MvvmDataGrid>
```

I then have a static handler `OnSingleClickEditPropertyChanged` which is registered as the `PropertyChangedCallback` on the `SingleClickEditProperty` attached property's metadata.

When that property invokes (*id est* the property was changed on the column), I am given a the `DataGridTextColumn`, when I need the `MvvmDataGrid` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/55369/142519.aspx)

Using this code you can found ancestor of the DataGridColumn - your DataGrid in visual tree. This code implemented as static function but you can change it to extension method with more "speaking" name like FindAncestor:

```
public static class UIElementExtensions

{

    public static T FindAncestor<T>(this UIElement control) where T: UIElement  
    {

        UIElement p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
        if (p != null)
        {
            if (p is T)
                return p as T;
            else
                return p.FindAncestor<T>();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
DataGrid p = dataGridColumn.FindAncestor< DataGrid >();
```

If you need to get your DataGrid from XAML try to use binding from [this article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/).

Good luck.

**UPDATE**:

I understand what is the matter. The next answer won't be so easy, but it's silverlight :)
So, why you cann't find DataGrid from DataGridColumn using VisualTreeHelper? Because, DataGridColumn doesn't exist in Visual Tree. DataGridColumn inherits from DependencyObject, not UIElement. 
Forget about VisualTree, and new **idea** will be like this: we **add addition attached property to DataGridColumn - named Owner, and bound DataGrid to this property**.
But, **DataGridColumn is DependencyObject** and **any bindings by ElementName don't work in silverlight 4**.
We can bind only to StaticResource. So, do it.
1) Owner attached property for DataGridColumn:

```
public class DataGridHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Owner",
            typeof(DataGrid),
            typeof(DataGridHelper),    
                    null));

    public static void SetOwner(DependencyObject obj, DataGrid tabStop)
    {
        obj.SetValue(OwnerProperty, tabStop);
    }

    public static DataGrid GetOwner(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataGrid)obj.GetValue(OwnerProperty);
    }
}
```

2) DataGrid Xaml (for instance):

```
<Controls:DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <Controls:DataGridTextColumn  h:DataGridHelper.Owner="[BINDING]"/>
    </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</Controls:DataGrid>
```

3) DataGrid Container - keeper of DataGrid instance in StaticResource:

```
public class DataGridContainer : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"Item", typeof(DataGrid),
typeof(DataGridContainer), null
);

    public DataGrid Item
    {
        get { return (DataGrid)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

4) Add to Resources of your view instance of DataGridContainer and bind DataGrid instance to Item property:

```
<c:DataGridContainer x:Key="ownerContainer" Item="{Binding ElementName=dg}"/>
```

Here, binding by ElementName will be worked.

5) Last step, we bind our DataGrid to attached property Owner (see p.2 and add next code to [BINDING] section):

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource ownerContainer}, Path=Item}
```

That's all. In code, if we have reference to DataGridColumn we can get owned DataGrid:

```
DataGrid owner = (DataGrid)dataGridColumn.GetValue(DataGridHelper.OwnerProperty);**
```

Hope this principle will help you.

Comment: I thought of this, but `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` throws an exception when I try to get the parent of a DataGridColumn.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "[BINDING]" in step 2.  Do you mean "{Binding}"?  If so, that's not going to help.

Comment: see step 5. I write want you should add in this place